# How to pass System.property to Android App from Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to be able to get system property from the application as:

`String isTesting = System.getProperty("IS_TESTING");`

I have tried to pass the argument using -D flag in gradle, like `./gradlew assemble -DIS_TESTING`. Or doing so:

```
task setCustomProp << {
    System.setProperty("IS_TESTING", "true")
}

preBuild.dependsOn setCustomProp
```

Even tried to change the `gradle.properties` adding this line:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-DIS_TESTING=true
```

But, none of those attempts results on getting the value on the application code. I'm simply trying to get like:

```java
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    String isTesting = System.getProperty("IS_TESTING");
}
```

Comment: "none of those attempts results on getting the value on the application code" -- the application code is running in Android, not on your development machine. There are no configurable system properties in Android, short of creating a custom ROM. If you want to have a system property on your development machine be embedded in your Android app. have your Gradle script use `buildConfigField` to put the system property value into `BuildConfig`, or use `resValue` to put the system property value in a string resource.

Comment: I'm trying to do so because I'm trying to change the environment variable here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3b6f6ca4d5fcee6f1bc6d6242e3e2ef136e4d546/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/systeminfo/AndroidInfoModule.java#L78-L80

React uses this `IS_TESTING` to change some configuration.

Comment: You will need to talk to the React Native team about that. I have no idea why they have that code there.

Comment: I can think of two scenarios where an `IS_TESTING` system property could be set. One is with a unit test, as that runs on the JVM, and so I assume we have a way of setting system properties when running unit tests. Another is if *Android* sets `IS_TESTING`, perhaps as part of an instrumented test run. Regardless, *you* have no way of setting it directly for an end-user run of an ordinary Android app.

Comment: I ended up changing the system properties inside the instrumented tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just add:

```
buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_TESTING", "true"
```

to build.gradle.

and then in your:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    boolean isTesting = BuildConfig.IS_TESTING
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but I'm afraid I'm stuck with `System.getProperty` since my problem is with other library - in fact with react native, you can have a look at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3b6f6ca4d5fcee6f1bc6d6242e3e2ef136e4d546/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/systeminfo/AndroidInfoModule.java#L78-L80